What are these directories in android studio? How to sort a directory
I am a programmer with obsessive-compulsive disorder, why are these things so messy?

In the picture below, what are these marks in the box?
Why is the identity different for different modules?
Can we change these signs to be the same?



Why can't these directories be sorted strictly by name?



I don't know if it's my fault that I didn't understand some features of Android studio, which caused this situation to happen;
who can help me understand these things.

